# Passing data in Angular

Tags: angular, components, navbar

How can I put an Angular component into the navbar?

[image]

Comment: Is the section in the red portion a separate component?

Comment: @VinceCyriac yes, actually the red highlighted and the right side of it is in one component. So I need to separate them...but first I need to know how to put a component to another component like navbar.

Comment: I imagine you should to have some like `<nav><ul><li>option1</li>...<li><my-component></my-component></li></ul></nav>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by separating two divs in one component to two components.

Then pass the data via parent-child relationship using @Input() decorator, from sidebar-dashboard to the list component.

Then the separated components which has no relationship, I used service to pass the data, so that whatever is selected in list component will produce its details in the results component.